# Cross-platform IAP from Unity3D using Soom-La

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I'm attempting to build IAP into my Unity3D game.

Currently I'm targeting only iPhone, but I always like to build reusable / extensible components.

To this end I'm trying to use http://soom.la/

I have put up my efforts at http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/228735-How-to-implement-single-IAP-to-unlock-full-version-of-game

But I can't see what I'm missing or doing wrong, as nobody is picking up on the Unity forum, I thought I would ask here. I suspect it may be iOS issue, so the question maybe belongs here.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out -- I have posted a detailed answer at http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/228735-How-to-implement-single-IAP-to-unlock-full-version-of-game

The process spans several posts, as there is a limit in number of pictures per post.